# Should I use Gparted or again dual boot system?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, gparted

I had dual booted Ubuntu alongwith windows 10 in my system. Now I need to increase the disk space because everytime Ubuntu shows running out of space error. I looked up on different ways suggesting me to boot a CD/DVD and use Gparted but I did not get a clear or safe idea on how to di it.

So now I am thinking on removing Ubuntu and again dual boot it. Is this the better way or should I follow steps on increasing disk space. (Clearly I am not able to understand or follow steps on increasing disk space.)

Comment: It is easier to resize than it is to reinstall which will require one or more resize operations as well as many other steps.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to resize?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in response to the out of disk space message is to manage disk space better.

Find out what is taking space. This app may help.
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/baobab/

Clean out old or over-sized logs, old package files, and move your data around given that information.

Your options are:

- erase files that you don't need
- use cloud storage, a shared partition with windows or a usb sick for
  data files
- Resize including extra room for future use in Ubuntu
- Create a new mount point and mount an additional partition, but this might require resizing windows anyway.
- Add a new drive and migrate or install Ubuntu onto the new drive.

Comment: I don't have extra files that accommodate space, it's just the program files and Ubuntu. But now I want to install new programs for which space is insufficient.

Comment: How much space have you allocated for ubuntu?  How much free space do you have in windows?  Logs can balloon into gigabyte files in some circumstances. How much free space did you start with?

Comment: For ubuntu I had allocated 12 GB out of which only 4 GB is available as free space. I have plenty free space in windows, around 400 GB.

Comment: It seems the best thing would be to resize Ubuntu with plenty of space like 100gb so you never will need to again. While you are at it you might create a data partition of 100gb  too. 

Manual resize may be two steps. First resize the partition then expand the file system to use the extra space. I think gparted gui  might take care of both of these steps.

Comment: You also might try creating a virtual machine in windows and give it a generous virtual disk if your hardware had the virtualization extensions. Then use file sharing between your VM and windows to store data.

Comment: You might wish to read the [GParted Manual - Advanced Partition Actions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-advanced-partition-actions) or see the example [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions) to learn more about partition resizing.